# Javascript won't read from "select" in a form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my code to read a value based off the selected item from a select list in my form, but it says it's undefined.  When I simply give the function a value and tell it to return the value, it reads, but won't take values from the form.

The following is the code I'm using

for the form (in html):

```
<form action="" id="orderForm" name="orderForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <select id="item" name='item' onchange="calculateCost()">
    <option value="None">Select Item</option>
    <option value="Candlestick">Candlestick ($10)</option>
    <option value="Bowl">Bowl ($10)</option>
    <option value="Burl_Bowl">Burl Bowl ($20)</option>
    <option value="Clock">Clock ($15)</option>
    <option value="Vase">Vase ($5)</option>
    <option value="Pen">Pen ($2)</option>
    <option value="Top">Spinning Top ($1)</option>
  </select>
<div id="totalPrice">hallo</div>
</form>
```

and the javascript reads

```
function calculateCost()
{

    var orderPrice = getItemPrice();
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = orderPrice;
}

var item_prices= new Array();
 item_prices["None"]=0;
 item_prices["Candlestick"]=10;
 item_prices["Bowl"]=10;
 item_prices["Burl_Bowl"]=20;
 item_prices["Clock"]=15;
 item_prices["Vase"]=5;
 item_prices["Pen"]=2;
 item_prices["Top"]=1;

function getItemPrice()
{
    var itemPrice = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["orderForm"];
    var selectedItem = theForm.elements["item"];
    itemPrice = item_prices[selectedItem.value];
    return itemPrice;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *[`HTMLCollection.item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item) is method of `HTML select element` Returns the specific node at the given zero-based index into the list. Returns null if the index is out of range.*

`theForm.elements["item"]` will return function expression of the `HTMLCollection.item` and which is causing the `undefined` value as `theForm.elements["item"]` does not have property `value`

Either pass `this` in `inline-event` or use other `id` and `name` attribute to select element than `item`

```js
function calculateCost(elem) {
  var orderPrice = getItemPrice(elem.value);
  document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = orderPrice;
}

var item_prices = [];
item_prices["None"] = 0;
item_prices["Candlestick"] = 10;
item_prices["Bowl"] = 10;
item_prices["Burl_Bowl"] = 20;
item_prices["Clock"] = 15;
item_prices["Vase"] = 5;
item_prices["Pen"] = 2;
item_prices["Top"] = 1;

function getItemPrice(val) {
  var itemPrice = 0;
  itemPrice = item_prices[val];
  return itemPrice;

}
```

```html
<form action="" id="orderForm" name="orderForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <select id="item" name='item' onchange="calculateCost(this)">
    <option value="None">Select Item</option>
    <option value="Candlestick">Candlestick ($10)</option>
    <option value="Bowl">Bowl ($10)</option>
    <option value="Burl_Bowl">Burl Bowl ($20)</option>
    <option value="Clock">Clock ($15)</option>
    <option value="Vase">Vase ($5)</option>
    <option value="Pen">Pen ($2)</option>
    <option value="Top">Spinning Top ($1)</option>
  </select>
  <div id="totalPrice">hallo</div>
</form>
```

**Edit:** Or just use `getElementById` => `var selectedItem = document.getElementById('item');` to access the `select` element.[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xa1wLxkk/)

Answer (score 0):

This entire operation could be simplified a bit as well.

```
var item_prices= new Array();
item_prices["None"]=0;
item_prices["Candlestick"]=10;
item_prices["Bowl"]=10;
item_prices["Burl_Bowl"]=20;
item_prices["Clock"]=15;
item_prices["Vase"]=5;
item_prices["Pen"]=2;
item_prices["Top"]=1;
```

EDIT, you should use an object here if you want to be correct.

```
item_prices = {
    None: 0,
    Candlestick: 10
};
// etc...

document.getElementById('item').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = item_prices[event.target.value];
});
```

Comment: Don't use an array with non-numeric keys. If you want to use it as an object, use an object: `var item_prices = {None: 0, Candlestick: 1, ...}`.

Comment: I was trying to change the fewest things possible so as not to confuse him... but yes, objects would be better.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize the OP actually used that. Still, if you provide an answer, do it right :)

Comment: That's fair and I've added an edit. I just figured since the actual bug in his code had nothing to do with the use of the array I'd leave it.